# Support Of Ngap and Nr-Rrc protocols filtering using SCAPY

Tags: scapy, 5g

In the given Pcapng file I am able to filter nr-rrc and ngap packets where as I am unable to view the same using Scapy.On researching I found out that the NGAP protocol messages are encoded into the SCTP payload.Is there any way I can decode it?

```
from scapy.all import *
packets = sniff(offline='ausf.pcapng')
ngap_packets = [pkt for pkt in packets if pkt.haslayer("NGAP")]
for pkt in ngap_packets:
    print(pkt.show())
```

The above code block prints no packets even though NGAP layers are present in the wireshark capture

Also how to filter nr-rrc packets using Scapy?